# Basic Authentication WCF service installed in SP2010 with claims authentication

Tags: sharepoint-2010, basic-authentication, claims-based-identity

This configuration works with SP2010 in classic mode or SP2007.

We have a WCF service that is installed as an Application under the Sharepoint web site.  This application uses Basic authentication.

I'm getting an **UnauthorizedAccessException**.
The exception message is

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

In the debugger, I notice that on the SPWeb object, the CurrentUser property is null.

What do I need to do to allow this user through basic authentication to be able to read the sharepoint lists?

```
 using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(url))

        {
            using (SPWeb rootWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                DataTable news = ReadNews(rootWeb, (uint)sizeNumber);

/// continues...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... better late than never.  I ran into this same problem today.  The problems comes when you publish .ASPX pages in the _Layouts folder, and then, when using Forms or Claims auth, make that custom page your first hit in a session (with no previously remembered login).  SharePoint authentication isn't fired by default (even if you inherit from the LayoutsPageBase class).  If you navigate to some other SharePoint page (such as _Layouts/15/Settings.aspx) and then come back, then the CurrentUser *is* filled in.  I had to use Reflector to get a better clue of what was going on, and how to fix it.  The short answer is, once you realize that the CurrentUser == null, you need to add this line of code:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(new UnauthorizedAccessException());
```

In my case, this code generates a challenge/response to the browser, which I used to log in, and immediately following this line of code, the CurrentUser object is filled in correctly.  Here is what my entire function ended up looking like:

```
public static bool isAdminAuthorized()
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext oContext ;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb oWeb ;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser oUser ;
    try
    {
        oContext = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current;
    }
    catch { throw new Exception("Can't obtain Sharepoint Context!"); }
    try
    {
        oWeb = oContext.Web;
    }
    catch { throw new Exception("Can't obtain Sharepoint web!"); }
    try
    {
        oUser = oWeb.CurrentUser;
    }
    catch { throw new Exception("Can't obtain Sharepoint current user!"); }
    if (oUser == null)
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(new UnauthorizedAccessException());
        oUser = oWeb.CurrentUser;
    }
    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup oGroup in oUser.Groups)
    {
        if (oGroup.Name.ToUpper().Contains("OWNER"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```